# How to read TRUE/FALSE value from Excel file through Java code

Tags: java

I am reading `true`/`false` as value from Excel through Java code. After reading I am getting 1/0 as output.

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(fileURL);
System.out.println(pkg);
XSSFReader reader = new XSSFReader(pkg);
System.out.println(reader);
SharedStringsTable sst = reader.getSharedStringsTable();
System.out.println(sst);
InputStream workbookData = reader.getWorkbookData();
```

What should I do for reading `true` as `true` and `false` as `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a piece of code which looks like this:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkboookFactory.create(...); // File, InputStream, etc
Cell cell = workbook.getSheet("foo").getRow(x).getCell(y);

Object value;
int cellType = cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA 
    ? cell.getCachedFormulaResultType() : cell.getCellType();
switch (cellType) {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: 
        value = cell.getBooleanCellValue();  
        break;

    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        break;

    ...
}
doStuff(value);
```

Comment: This will now work because if i am processing(reading) 1 from excel then also it will convert into TRUE. i am ETL developer. we are reading value from excel and migrated into database.

Comment: Tweaked my answer to use a common piece of code I use fore dealing with cells

Comment: here "foo" is replaced by the fileURL path and workbook is replaced by the workbookData.

Comment: Cell cell = workbook.getSheet("foo").getRow(x).getCell(y);  here "foo" is replaced by the fileURL path and workbook is replaced by the workbookData. i have done these correction after that i am getting error message like "the method getSheet(String) is undefine for the type inputstream.

Comment: Incorrect, "foo" should be a sheet name within your excel spreadsheet. I've added a mention of WorkbookFactory.